# How do I write methods that take the output of the .col() method as input?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have read the documentation on [Writing Functions Taking Eigen Types as Parameters](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html), and since all my Eigen containers are Arrays I decided to create a function prototype like this:

```
template <typename Derived>
void Threshold(Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>& params) 
// I tried void Threshold(Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>& params) as well, same outcome
{
  params = (params >= 0.0f).template cast<float>();
}
```

The problem is, when I call this function like this:

```
Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> arr;
// fill it with stuff
Threshold(arr.col(0)); // error!
```

I get the following error:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Array<float, -1, -1>
>::ColXpr {aka Eigen::Block<Eigen::Array<float, -1, -1>, -1, 1, true>}’ to
‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Array<float, -1, -1>, -1, 1, true> >&’
```

Is my function template wrong? How do I pass the output of the `.col()` method of an `Eigen::Array` object to a function?

Comment: I mean, just looking at the error message, your function takes ``Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Block<...> >`` and you're giving it ``Eigen::Block<..>``.

Comment: @aruisdante see the link in the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `Ref<>` class which will allow you to write a function that accepts both columns of a matrix and vectors without templates nor copies:

```
void threshold(Ref<ArrayXf> params) {
    params = (params >= 0 ).cast<float>();
}
ArrayXf  a;
ArrayXXf A;
/* ... */
threshold(a);
threshold(A.col(j));
```